# Include a vb script in an ASP page

Tags: vba, asp-classic

I have a vbscript which takes a csv file and uploads its content to the database. I need to include that script in an ASP page. the script should be present in the asp page itself and not placed externally, ie, i dont want the asp page to set a reference to the externally located dll but include the code in the asp itself. can it be done?

this is the vbscript I have.

http://pastebin.com/vuzUhTDM

Any help will be genuinely appreciated.

Comment: looks like a duplicate post of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12798401/add-the-excel-sheet-imported-directly-into-the-table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the vb6 code can just be reused in classic asp vbscript. You'll have to declare your variables a bit different as vbscript only has Variants..

Thus for the recordset declaration, instead of this:

```
Dim rs1 As New ADODB.Recordset, rs2 As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset
```

You'll have to do this

```
Dim rs1 , rs2, rst 
Set rs1=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.recordset")
Set rs2=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.recordset")
Set rst=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.recordset")
```

*[I didn't see any connection object in your code example.. just the use of  db.ConnectionString.. Make sure you create the connection object db also with the same logic.]*

For the simple variables you also just create a high-level variant-type and the subtypes (string, long, integer...) will be assigned at runtime by assigning values to the variables.
Thus, instead of this:

```
Dim eno As Long
Dim fname As String
Dim fname1 As String
Dim fno1 As Integer
Dim fno As Integer
Dim mstr As String
Dim flds() As String
Dim valid_data As Boolean
Dim errstr As String
Dim errcnt As Integer
Dim pickupid As Long
Dim cancel_rec As String
Dim bkno As Double
Dim sReceipt_no As Long
```

You can do this:

```
Dim eno , fname , fname1 , fno1 , fno , mstr, valid_data, errstr, errcnt, pickupid, cancel_rec, bkno, sReceipt_no 
Dim flds()
```